# Anchor not working correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If you click "Tip en ven" at the following page, the screen "jumps" down, why?
the anchor is right after the  tag? So it should be scrolling to the top of the page, when showing the div?

[You can see it here](http://cabiweb.inforce.dk/sektionsforside/underside1)

Comment: Forgot, the anchorlinks is right after the body tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It tries to set the page with the anchor on top. Since the anchor is in the middle of the page it then tries to scroll it to a location where the anchor is on top.

Comment: Im not quite sure what you mean? There is no anchor in the middle of the page? The anchor is in the top of the html code?

Comment: Happy to be able to help! Default behvaiour in html can be quite tricky and unforgiving.